# Let $f(z):=e^{\frac 1 z}, {z \in \mathbb C \setminus\{0\}}$.What values of $z$ are $ f(z)=re^{i\phi}$ for $r\in(0, \infty), \phi\in\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Consider $f(z):=e^{\frac 1 z}, {z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}}$.

For which values are $f(z)$ real ?

I've considered $e^{\frac 1 {a+ib}} = e^{\frac {a-ib} {a^2+b^2}}$.

For which values are $f(z)$ purely imaginary ?

I've $e^{\frac {a-ib} {a^2+b^2}} = e^{\frac a {a^2+b^2}} (\cos(\frac b {a^2+b^2}) - i \sin (\frac b {a^2+b^2})) $, so $\frac b {a^2+b^2} =\frac {\pi} 2  + k\pi$ for $f(z) \in \mathbb C\setminus \mathbb R$. Thus I deduce $b = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt {1-4(\frac\pi 2+ \pi k)^2 a^2}} {2(\frac\pi 2+ \pi k)}$.

Next what values of $z$ is $f(z) = re^{i\phi}$ for $r \in (0, \infty), \phi \in \mathbb R$ ?

How do I do the last part ? And can the first two parts be solved easier ? I think it is quite messy.

**Please do not use complex logarithm or advanced complex theory, because I'm not introduced to this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider the simpler function $g(z)=e^z$. For real $ x$ and $y$ we have $g(x+iy)= e^x\cos y +ie^x\sin y$, so $g(x+iy)$ is real precisely when $\sin y =0$, *i.e.*, when $y=\pi k$ for integral $k$. That's the same as saying $z= x +\pi ki$.

This means $f(z)=g(\frac1z)$ is real when $\frac1z$ is of the form $x +\pi ki$, so $z=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{x +\pi ki}}$ (excluding the case  $x=0=k$ which makes the denominator $0$).

For the pure imaginary case, we instead see that $g(x+iy)$ is pure imaginary precisely when $\cos y=0$, and a line of reasoning similar to that above yields that $f(z)$ is pure imaginary for $z=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{x +(\frac {\pi}{2}+\pi k)i}}$.

For the last part, suppose $g(x +iy)=re^{i\phi}$. Then $e^x=r$ and $\cos y +i\sin y =\cos \phi +i\sin \phi$. So $x=\log r$ and $ y=\phi +2\pi k$. As before, we then have that $f( z)=re^{i\phi}$ when $z=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{\log r +(\phi +2\pi k)i}}$, excluding the case that makes the denominator $0$ ($r=1$ and $\phi=0=k$).

I hope there are no typos in this!

Answer (score 0):

We have $$re^{i\phi} =e^{\ln{r} + i\phi}  $$ so you are looking  for  $$z= \frac{1}{\ln{r} + i\phi +2ik\pi} $$

Comment: You don't answer the question, and $z$ could also be $\frac{1}{\ln r + i \phi + 2 \pi i}$, for example.

Comment: Could you tell if my first calculations are correct (two first questions ?) - Have you used these in your answer ?

Comment: Your first answer isn't correct. You should have proceeded as in 2